# Saving GUI state in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am writing a program that will compare the changes in GUI state in different runs of the same app. For this reason I need to probe all the views that is in focus and detect their state according to their type; for example whether a radio-button is on or off, or the check box is selected or not etc. Please help me to find some workarounds to apply in my apps source code.

Actually I am injecting my code into an app to get information about the GUI state for my research. For that I need to inject a java stub within the activity which will probe all the visible views and get their state. So, I do not have access to individual views that I can save the state or prob for. I can only learn the state by writing a generic stub that will prob all the views and test it. Something similar to Robotium. But here I am allowed to write code in java anticipating I have access to the source.

So the generic stub will be something like this,

```
View views[]=getAllViews();
for each view in views
 probe its state
done
```

I need my program do something similar to this.

Comment: No need for workarounds.  Use SharedPreferences.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Actually I am injecting my code into an app to get information about the GUI state for my research. For that I need to inject a java stub within the activity which will probe all the visible views and get their state. So, I do not have access to individual views so that I can save the state or prob it. I can only learn the state by writing a generic stub that will prob all the views and test it. Something similar to Robotium. But here I am allowed to write code in java anticipating I have access to the source.

Comment: Is this in an Activity or a Fragment?  I would use getView() when appropriate in the Fragment lifecycle if you are in a Fragment.  If you are in an Activity, do you access to the root layout?  If so, "get your root View, cast it to a ViewGroup, call getChildCount() and getChildAt(), and recurse as needed." [CommonsWare]

Comment: Yes I got the page you mentioned. I am writing a complete solution, I will post it later.